# Google Maps address autofill Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing an issue. I am using the google maps api address auto fill. When i run the sample code provided by the google it works fine. But when i use it in my application It works fine for small input like which have small country, city name. But when i use it for long inputs it gave this error on console.

```
new:1381 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

When i click on link it take me to this piece of code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            var valShort  =place.address_components[i].short_name;
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code:

```
<script>

    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = { 

        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
        country: 'long_name',    
    };    

    function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {

                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                var valShort  =place.address_components[i].short_name;
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
        }
    }  

</script>
```

Comment: You wrote "But when i use it for long inputs" it fails.  Please provide a sample of the failing input.

Comment: if the input is "Saddar, Lahore, Punjab" it works fine. But if the input is "Saddar road 2, Lahore, Punjab" it fails.

Comment: Are you selecting an entry from the drop down?

Comment: Yes i am selecting it from drop down.

Comment: I can replicate the error on [this example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform), but only when I past the address in, then hit return, if I start typing and select the entry from the drop down, the `address_components` field exists.

Comment: How can i solve it? In my case it is giving error in both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether address_components is there or not.

As per the [Autocomplete class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Autocomplete) reference:

> If the user enters the name of a Place that was not suggested by the
>   control and presses the Enter key, or if a Place detail request fails,
>   a place_changed event will be fired that contains the user input in
>   the name property, with no other properties defined.

So you need to handle the case when the event is fired but the place you get back has nothing but a name. One way to deal with this is by falling back on sending a [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) or [Place Text Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) request. Geocoding is enough for addresses, but if you also want to find businesses, you'll need Places Text Search.